# WooCommerce Add to Cart in Ajax not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

In my current custom theme WooCommerce all standard functionality is not working with Ajax. I did some research and this should be default behaviour if i'm not mistaken. I followed the WooCommerce integration guide but not sure why it's not working.

Not sure what is going on. Even when i delete my customized options in functions.php the Ajax calls are not being executed. I've got no error in my console. Seems like the css classes are there like **ajax_add_to_cart** but nothing is executed like the .js file of woocommerce does not exist.

I'm testing in the default created page of WooCommerce called **Shop**.

Any help would be appreciated.

**woocommerce.php**
*: this is the default woocommerce (page.php copy)*

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php woocommerce_content(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**functions.php** *Added the following customizable functions into the theme*

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 10);
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end', 10);
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 30 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_result_count', 20 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close', 5 );

add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'my_theme_wrapper_start', 10);
add_action('woocommerce_after_main_content', 'my_theme_wrapper_end', 10);

add_filter( 'add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_single_add_to_cart_text' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_single_add_to_cart_text' );

function woo_custom_single_add_to_cart_text() {

    return __( 'Voeg Toe', 'woocommerce' );

}

function my_theme_wrapper_start() {
    echo '<section id="main">';
}

function my_theme_wrapper_end() {
    echo '</section>';
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'woocommerce_support' );
function woocommerce_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}
```

**My HTML Add to Cart Button Code looks like this:**

```
<a rel="nofollow" 
   href="/theme/shop/?add-to-cart=508" 
   data-quantity="1" data-product_id="508" 
   data-product_sku="" 
   class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart">
   Add to Cart
</a>
```

**Also having this in header.php** *not sure if this can mess up WooCommerce functionality*

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you have any error in browser console?

Comment: @Hatef No i'm not getting any error in the console, that makes me wonder what is going on right now. Every WooCommerce functionality works but without ajax.